# C++: using class member and static function of same name but different parameters fails

Tags: function, c++11, static, stl, member

I want to have a class with a static and a member function of the same name and doing exactly the same thing. Once to be able to call it from an instance, and once to use it with functions from std-algorithm. Minimal example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class foo {
public:
  inline static bool isOne(const foo & s) {
    return s.bar == 1;
  }
  // if I uncomment the next line, count_if won't compile anymore
  //inline bool isOne() const { return isOne(*this); }

private:
  int bar;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<foo> v;
  auto numones=std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), foo::isOne);
  return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles and works as expected. However, if I uncomment the member function isOne(), because, maybe, I would also like to have

```
foo x; x.isOne();
```

in my main(), things break horribly both with clang 6.0 and gcc 5.3. The clang error is

```
no matching function for call to 'count_if'
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Predicate'
count_if(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Predicate __pred)
```

and the gcc error is basically the same in a different wording.

I am obviously doing things wrong, but I am currently out of ideas how to fix this. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused due to the fact that `count_if` is a function template, not a function.

The fact that the non-`static` member is not suitable for `count_if` is not taken into consideration when deducing the type of the template parameter.

You'll notice the same error had your class had an overload

```
inline static bool isOne(const foo & s, int) { ... }
```

The only way to resolve this to help the compiler with the overload resolution. That be one by explicitly casting the function

```
auto numones = std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                             static_cast<bool(&)(const foo&)>(foo::isOne));
```

or by using explicit template parameters.

```
auto numones = std::count_if<decltype(v.begin()),  // First template parameter
                             bool(&)(const foo&)>  // Second template parameter
                             (v.begin(), v.end(), foo::isOne);
```

---

You can avoid these problems by following sound software engineering practices.

Move the `static` member function out the class. Make it a global function or a function in a namespace of your own application.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

namespace MyApp
{
   class foo {
      public:
         inline bool isOne() const { return (bar == 1); }

      private:
         int bar;
   };

   inline bool isOne(foo const& s)
   {
      return s.isOne();
   }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<MyApp::foo> v;
  auto numones=(v.begin(), v.end(), MyApp::isOne);
  return 0;
}
```

Given that, you can use ADL to invoke the namespace version of the function without having to explicitly use `MyApp::isOne`.

```
MyApp::foo f;
isOne(f);   // OK. Uses ADL to find the right function.
```

Comment: While I am not a fan of having specialised functions more or less pollute a namespace (be it global or other), your solution seems to lead to the cleanest / easiest possible code from the perspective of a user of that class. Thank you, accepted.

Answer (score 3):

when taking a pointer to an overloaded method you need to tell the compiler which overload you want to take a pointer to, you can do this with a static cast to the appropriate method type:

```
 auto numones=std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), static_cast<bool(*)(const foo&)>(foo::isOne));
```

Comment: Thanks. That does indeed work. But also add a lot of boilerplate code which I feel somewhat unnecessary and counterproductive for users of the class.
Is there anything in the class design / definition I can change to make things easier?

Comment: make the names of your functions different. Its an unfortunate corner of c++ that there is no easy way to get a pointer to a specific overload of a method/function

Comment: you could also publish typedefs for commonly used method types, that would at least make the static_cast shorter

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple other ways to solve this problem, namely:

- Make the static member, a friend function
- Use lambda

I recommend the second, so do this:

```
auto numones=std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](foo const& f) { return foo::is one(f); });
```

This solution allows you to keep both functions and does not introduce any ambiguity.